# How to fix a Circular Reference Issue with WCF

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a normalized set of tables.  Owner, Dog, License (those are the major ones)  Every Owner can have multiple Dogs and every Dog can have multiple Licenses.  There are a few reference tables associated to each of those objects like Address for the Owner, Breed and Color for the Dog and LicenseType for the License.  I do not believe those are my issue.

This is essentialy Code First (using the Reverse Engineer Code First tool) so I have no EDMX.  I am having a circular reference issue and it is killing me.  All of the articles I read say just to put the IsReference = true attribute on.  This is great if it is only a Parent-Child releationship.  I have a Grandparent-Parent-Child relationship.  I have tried [this](http://chabster.blogspot.com/2008/02/wcf-cyclic-references-support.html) article with no luck.  I see so many articles out there but most of them are 4+ years old.  I want what should be done and works in .Net 4 (not 4.5)  I can't be the only one out there with this situation.  My brain is mush at this point.

Here is my code that grabs the object from the database.  It works like a champ.

```
using (DogLicensingContext db = new DogLicensingContext()) {
    Result = (from l in db.Licenses
        .Include(x => x.Dog) // Get the Dog on this License
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner)
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Title)
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Dogs) // Gets me all of their Dogs
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Dogs.Select(d => d.Licenses))
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Dogs.Select(d => d.Licenses.Select(l => l.TagStyle)))
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Dogs.Select(d => d.Breed))
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Dogs.Select(d => d.Color))
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Dogs.Select(d => d.Color1))
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Dogs.Select(d => d.HairLength))
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Dogs.Select(d => d.Sex))
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Address)
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Address.State)
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Phones)
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Emails)
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Phones.Select(p => p.PhoneType))
        .Include(x => x.Dog.Owner.Emails.Select(p => p.EmailType))
    where l.BarCode == BarCode
    select l).FirstOrDefault();
} // using the database
```

Here is a trimmed down view of the Owner and Dog classes.

Owner Class:

```
[DataMember]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedOn { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public int ID { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; private set; }
```

Dog Class:

```
[DataMember]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedOn { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public int ID { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<License> Licenses { get; set; }
```

It works in the test client like this.  If I make the ICollection Dogs or the ICollection Licenses a DataMember is when I get the StackOverflow.

So how can I get the collections to come across WCF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ReferencePreservingDataContractFormat` [here](http://pastebin.com/jVwpCMmi).

And then mark your wcf service methods (operation contracts) with the attribute:

```
[OperationContract]
[ReferencePreservingDataContractFormat]
List<Dog> GetDogsAndOwners();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Salvador Sarpi.  I added those classes to my project.  Put [DataMember] in front of my the two ICollection<xxx> properties and ran it.  It gets the data but can not serialize it.  StackOverflow still.  I also added the Attribute as you show above.

Comment: You don't have to put the ReferencePreservingDataContractFormat attribute at the property, you need to put it in the WCF operation (in the interface of your service)

Comment: I know, this is what it looks like.    [OperationContract]
 [ReferencePreservingDataContractFormat]
 License GetLicenseByBarCode(string BarCode);

Comment: did you turn off lazy loading and proxy creation?

Comment: This is what my Context looks like:
public DogLicensingContext() : base("Name=DogLicensingContext") {
 base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
 base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
} - same Stack Overflow

Comment: Try removing all [DataMember] attribute from your poco classes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19780/discussion-between-salvador-sarpi-and-grandizer)

Comment: Thank you @Salvador Sarpi, I will most likely not be able to work on this today.  Chat on Monday would be kewl.  I really appreciate your time thus far.

Comment: yeah, you just let me know and we can see whats the problem.